# Java Swing Application issue in IntelliJ vs Eclipse

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception

I created a project in Java back in 2017 that included a GUI. At the time I used Eclipse. I am now using IntelliJ and am trying to recreate the project there. It still runs fine in Eclipse but when I run it in IntelliJ I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at Application.load(Application.java:619)
    at Application.initActions(Application.java:549)
    at Application.<init>(Application.java:47)
    at Main$1.run(Main.java:14)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

It would appear that the exact lines it has a problem with are:

```
   private ImageIcon load(final String name) {
        return new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/" + name + ".png"));
    }
```

I have not changed the name of the folder icons nor the files in it. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the value of method parameter `name` when the exception is thrown? Are you certain that such a file exists in the `icons` folder? Can you post details of the folders in your project in IntelliJ ?

Comment: I believe it is "Refresh" based on the following code:  ' private void initActions() {
        refreshAction = new AbstractAction("Refresh", load("Refresh")) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 55365373393992164L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                refreshData();
            }
        }; ' the folders I have are: .idea, icons, out, src, target inside src: main, test

Comment: It's difficult to read code in a comment. [Edit] your question and add the code. In any case, all question details should be in the question and not in comments. I was actually asking you to add more details to your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!!! Your questions actually helped me find the answer. I was missing a folder inside src/main. It now runs! A big thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Abra's question actually helped me find the answer. I was missing a folder and its files in src/main.